# Почему честь отдают?

Tags: фразеология

Вопрос об этимологии слова "почитать" натолкнул меня на встречный вопрос: а почему, собственно, честь отдают? Я понимаю, что можно отдать дань уважения, отдать долг, но честь-то? А как же "береги честь смолоду..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько понимаю, вопрос относится к филологии и не связан с историей самого обычая (о ней можно, кстати, поспорить).

Глагол "отдать" несет не только значение "передать от одного другому", но и "оказать", "воздать". Сравните "отдать почести", "отдать последний долг". 
Смысл в том, что никто на собственную честь её отдающего не покушается. Отдают честь в данном выражении **кому, но не чью**. Это та честь, который "получающий" сам заслужил. не только воинскую, кстати.

Версия с Петровским уставом, конечно, интересная, но как-то не вяжется "честь имею" и "честь отдать".

Comment: Отдавали воинскую честь не кому-то, а чему-то, конкретно званию и мундиру. Выражение "отдать честь", вопреки моему первоначальному предположению о влиянии петровского устава, распространилось позже,и было связано как раз с появлением понятия о чести мундира.

Comment: >Выражение "отдать честь"... распространилось позже,

Когда и почему? Вы не делаете никаких предположениях о причине такого сочетания за исключением расплывчатой отсылки к выражению "честь имею", которое ничего не объясняет. 

>Отдавали воинскую честь не кому-то, а чему-то, конкретно званию и мундиру.
  
Никогда. Какому "мундиру", Господь с вами. Это у буржуев что-то такое было. В России - вполне конкретным персонам и некоторым местам, наподобие мавхолея в СССР.

Comment: 2. В СССР, честь может конкретным персонам и отдавали, а в царской армии честь отдавалась именно мундиру, о чём прямо прописано в уставе Российской империи http://www.bergenschild.narod.ru/Reconstruction/archive/ustav_internal_service/ustav_internal_service_1.htm см. статью 30.

Comment: Цитаты приведите. Я как-то не склонен верить отсылке в никуда.
А вообще это все более и более уводит от вопроса. 
Допустим, я поверю. Это как-то скажется на понимании почему "отдать"?

ЗЫ "Отданіе чести есть оказаніе почета воинскому званію того, кому отдается честь, и носимому имъ мундиру" - если Вы об этом, то мундир упоминается вскользь. О пышности оборотов того времени я даже не упоминаю. Не мундиру - а "носимому мундиру". Т.е. - все равно персоне.

Comment: 4. Поверите вы или нет, мне в общем-то безразлично. Поэтому и в комментарии к вашим словам, я лишь указал на то, что честь отдавали не кому-то, а чему-то и привёл ссылку. То что в пылу спора вы не очень удосужились её прочитать, проблемы не мои. Приведу цитату ещё раз, - "Отдание чести есть оказание почёта ВОИНСКОМУ ЗВАНИЮ того, кому отдаётся честь, и носимому им МУНДИРУ. И сейчас, если человек не одет в военную форму, или не имеет воинского звания, отдавать ему воинское приветствие не обязательно.

Comment: Ссылку давайте. Простите, но мне тоже безразличны Ваши цитаты без явного указания источника. Нет проверяемого источника - значит Вы и есть её автор.
На предложение перейти к филологии Вы тоже не откликнулись.

> сейчас, если **человек** не одет в военную форму, или не имеет воинского звания, отдавать ему воинское приветствие не обязательно.  
  
А если мундир без человека, Вы ему честь типа отдаете? "Яплакаль"

Кстати, вы в каком звании, позвольте поинтересоваться?

Comment: 6. Я Вам дал прямую ссылку на устав 1910 года, какую ссылку вам надо ещё?  
Воинское приветствие и сейчас отдаётся знамени полка или флагу корабля. Честь отдавали же ЗВАНИЮ и МУНДИРУ. Если из этого не было хотя бы одного, то честь отдавать было необязательно.  
Когда честь отдаётся не кому-то, а чему-то, то объяснять дальше - по-моему бессмысленно, так как становится понятным причина обязательности действия и уместность употребления слова "честь". Глагол "отдать" и существительное "честь" с тех времён значение не поменяли и как они согласуются видно из любого словаря.

Comment: Мне - ничего. А Вам надо давать ссылку на точную цитату, на которой строится Ваше умозаключение. Так вообще-то принято в приличных местах.  

>Честь отдавали же ЗВАНИЮ и МУНДИРУ.  

Нет. Человеку, имеющему звание и мундир. Без человека в мундире честь не отдаётся. 

>Когда честь отдаётся не кому-то, а чему-то,

Нет. 

>Глагол "отдать" и существительное "честь" с тех времён значение не поменяли и как они согласуются видно из любого словаря.

Не об этом речь. **Вы свою идею насчет происхождения от "честь имею" снимаете?**

Answer (score 4):

Сейчас уже отдают не честь, а воинское приветствие.

Честь же начали отдавать с середины XVIII века. Произошло это в связи с распространением понятия о чести мундира. Воинскую честь отдавали не человеку, а званию и мундиру.

"Отданіе чести есть оказаніе почета воинскому званію того, кому отдается честь, и носимому имъ мундиру; оно одинаково обязательно какъ для подчиненныхъ и младшихъ въ отношеніи начальниковъ и старшихъ, такъ и для начальниковъ и старшихъ въ отношеніи 
подчиненныхъ и младшихъ; и те другіе должны взаимно отдавать честь другъ другу."
Это из Устава внутренней службы 1910 года.

При Петре I отдавали не честь, а комплимент и отдавали только старшему по званию, причём различными способами, но без козыряния, появившегося только в конце XVIII века, из-за распространения громоздких головных уборов, которые было трудно снять.

Comment: Не по делу. А по делу автор говорит не хочет.
"Честь мундира", однако.

Comment: Уважаемый, Вы минус свой заслужили своей манерой ведения спора.
Я долго 
А вот бегать по старым вопросам в поисках чего бы тайно заминусить в надежде, что Вас не вычислят - это, простите, ниже моего понимания. 

Засим - всё. Спорить с Вами в таком тоне я не собираюсь.

Comment: 1. В вашем ответе закончились комментарии поэтому отвечу здесь.  
"Без человека в мундире честь не отдаётся" - Вы можете привести источник ваших сакральных знаний, потому как воинские уставы пишут обратное, а вне уставов, честь, если она не девичья, оказывают и воздают.  
Аналогия с "честь имею", оказалась правильной, так как навела на нужные источники, но насколько "отдать честь" и "честь имею" связаны между собой, я на данный момент не знаю, поэтому в текущей редакции ответа, никакого "честь имею" и нет.

Comment: Я вам отвечу после того как Вы прокоментирете свой анонимный минус в старой теме и дадите точную ссылку на свою цитату.

Довольно неприлично требовать от других того, что сами игнорируете. 

А источник моих сведений - воинские уставы. В том числе и тот, на который Вы изволили сослаться. 

Про аналогию я Вас не спрашиваю. Вы снимаете свою идею насчет происхождения "отдать честь" от "честь имею"? Больше спрашивать не буду.  

ЗЫ Вот Антон Павлович жалеет, что Вас не встретил... Мужик отдающий честь мундиру без владельца внутри него - это ж какой сюжет!

Comment: >При Петре I 
Полное собрание фактических, исторических и лингвистических ляпов, построенных на неверно понятых сведениях из Вики. 

>отдавали не честь, а комплимент   
  
Нет. Комплимент не *отдается*.

>и отдавали только старшему по званию, 
Кроме СССР и РФ - это и сейчас.

> причём различными способами, 
И сейчас так

>но без козыряния, появившегося только в конце XVIII века, из-за распространения громоздких головных уборов, которые было трудно снять.   

Честь часто отдаётся без козыряния. Вы не понимаете смысла слов, о которых беретесь судить.

Спорить об этом дальше не буду. Не по теме.

Comment: 4. Честь сейчас не отдаётся вообще, ныне это уже архаизм, также как и "отдать комплимент" "Буде же генерал знатной, то только офицеры обыкновенной поклон отдают держа ружье в руках. И сколь скоро оный в квартиру свою станет, то того часу штаб-юфицеры, собравшись к нему пойдут, и отдав комплимент, отводят полки," из устава 1716 года (глава LVII часть 3). Отдание чести в петровском уставе, кстати, тоже есть, но значит оно приветствие или прощание с главнокомандующим при отъезде из места дислокации войск, или прибытии в него.

Comment: Комплимент не отдается, он, насколько я понимаю, делается.

Comment: 7. В современном значении - да. Но во времена Петра I так называли ещё и просто знак уважения. Кстати, в цирке поклон до сих пор называют комплимент. Пример употребления выражения "отдать комплимент", в петровском уставе я привёл в посте выше вашего.

Answer (score 4):

Отдать честь. Здесь глагол ОТДАТЬ в значении 7 по Ожегову:

7.что. Произвести что-н. (в соответствии со знач. следующего далее сущ.). Отдать приказ (приказать). Отдать распоряжение (распорядиться). Отдать воинскую честь - оказать воинскую почесть. Отдать поклон (поклониться; устар.). Поклон ведь тоже никому не отдают в прямом значении.

Отдать честь - произвести приветствие.

Comment: Людмила, это-то понятно. Людям, хоть как-то с армией связанным даже напоминать не надо, что "честь" - это "приветствие". 
Я даже более скажу, изначально это действие называлось салютованием, потом "воинским приветствием". "Отдать честь" - это что-то вроде разговорного варианта.
Но вопрос - почему именно "отдать".

Comment: Согласен  с  бегемотусом.  Фразеологизмы  "отдать  честь" и  "честь  имею"  не  связаны,  на  мой  взгляд.  А  на  вопрос  Людмила  ответила.

Comment: bernard, я не очень понимаю, надо ли со мной соглашаться. Мой оппонент не подтвердил и не опроверг то, что он имел ввиду именно это, т.е. связь (вернее - происхождение) одного с другим.  

Касательно ответы Людмилы. Я тоже не понял главного - строго по поставленному вопросу. Почему именно "отдать". Образование явно искусственное, не стихийно возникшее, людьми придуманное, поэтому вопрос "почему" в данном случае вполне корректен. Не принести, не воздать, не оказать... Выбран весьма неожиданный глагол в не самом главном значении.
В большинстве языков это название восходит к латинскому saluto.

Answer (score 2):

Жест возник в средневековой Западной Европе, по одной из версий, от движения руки для приподнимания забрала рыцарями при встрече с кем-либо в знак мирных намерений и приветствия.